# Is it possible to git-diff a file against standard input?

Tags: git

Let's say I'm editing a file.  If I save the file, `git-diff` will give me its changes relative to the index.  I'd like to get the changes relative to the index without saving the file first – for a "realtime" diff.

One solution is to write the unsaved changes to a temporary file (i.e. save the file elsewhere), write the staged file to another temporary file (`git show :file > tempfile2`) then `git-diff tempfile tempfile2`.  However that seems inelegant.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just save the file? What speaks against it?

Comment: It would be nice to avoid saving the file if I can just use a pipe.

Comment: @AndyStewart: why is it nice? Just throw a file in tmp. It's not hard, it's not a lot of work...certainly a lot less than trying to work around git's requirements (but see Ash Berlin's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improving upon Ash Berlin's answer.

This allows you to use the nice features of git-diff.

```
git show :file | git diff --no-index -- - temp_saved_path
```

Note that this still might not be as convenient as you'd like, because you still have to write to a temp file. Until you save the file, the changes are either not on disk at all (in-memory only), or in some kind of temporary file that is editor-dependent. It's possible that Vim could do this seamlessly in one step, but I'm not familiar enough to say.

Comment: Vim lets you pass content to the stdin of the external command being called.  So I now write the index version of the file to a temp file and pass the in-memory file to stdin: `git show :file > tmpfile && git diff -- tmpfile -`.

Comment: Also, if one or both of the file paths is outside the git repo then `--no-index` is automatically inferred.

Answer (score 17):

Since [git 1.5.1](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.1.txt?id=v1.8.2#n29) there's been an option to diff against stdin - it's just not been documented

`$ echo foo | git diff --no-index -- my_file -`

On playing with this a bit more I realized this might not be what the OP (or I) wanted - it diffs the current state of the file to stdin, not the last committed state of the file to stdin. Something like this will do that

`$ echo foo | diff -u <(git show :my_file) -`

Note this does mean invoking diff directly which might not pick up some settings in your git config. Basically as ams says in his answer.