# How to word-diff two streams using git?

Tags: git, diff

The following git diff command requires two files.

```
git --no-pager diff --no-index -U0 --word-diff -- file1 file2
```

But they won't work for nonfiles, such as pipes.

```
$ git --no-pager diff --no-index -U0 --word-diff -- <(echo a) <(echo b)
error: /dev/fd/63: unsupported file type
fatal: cannot hash /dev/fd/63
```

Does anybody know what is called by `git` to actually perform the comparison? Is there a way compare non-files?

Comment: Following this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516177/6309), I think you would need temp files at some point.